# The nested query is not supported

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a query that is similar to the following (my actual query has three sections like this and then `Concat`s them together and applies some additional filters and sorting).

```
var articles = from p in Repository.Query<Product>()
               let article = p.Article
               let office = p.TariffCategory.Office
               where p.IsDeleted == false
               select new
               {
                   OfficeId = office.Id,
                   Office = office.Name,
                   Category = p.TariffCategory.Description,
                   ArticleId = article.Id,
                   Article = article.Title,
                   Destinations = p.ProductDestinations.Select(d => new { Id = d.DestinationId, Name = d.Destination.Description }),
                   GlobalDestinations = p.AllDestinationsInOffice,
                   article.LastReviewedDate,
                   article.CreatedDate,
                   article.CreatedByEmployee
               };
```

Everythings seems right except my assignment to `Destinations`. That line produces the following error.

> The nested query is not supported. Operation1='UnionAll' Operation2='MultiStreamNest'

If I remove that line, everything works as expected. Is there any way to perform a query like this?

Comment: I looks like the output of one of the other two queries us the same name as one of the objects on the line that is giving you the error.

Comment: @jdweng: Which output is the same?

Comment: Is Destinations define someplace else in the code?  Maybe a class name.  Maybe Description is use elsewhere in the code.

Comment: @jdweng: This will be converted to a SQL query. Destinations is a related database table. I don't see where any of the items use the same name.

Comment: The error message says "nested" which can only happen if you are reference an object declared someplace else.

Comment: @jdweng: It's a nested query operation. I don't see any indication it has to do with objects using the same name, and don't see how that could be an issue here.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it's not possible. As a work around, you can select the `DestinationID`, do a `.Join()`, and then re-select the result with your destinations. It does get very verbose, but you could write a helper method (especially helpful when removing the duplicate select)

Comment: Thanks @Rob, perhaps you're right. However, I'm having a little trouble visualizing what you suggested with `.Join()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a bit of a think, and rather than doing a join as I suggested, it may make sense to start the query at `ProductDestination`. What we're interested in is a row for each product+destination combination, much like you'd see via regular SQL queries. Once we've got that, we can apply grouping to the result so that we're closer to the representation you had

```
var data = Repository.Query<ProductDestination>()
    .Where(pd => !pd.Product.IsDeleted)
    .Select(pd => 
    new {   
       Product = pd.Product,
       Destination = pd.Destination,
    })
    .GroupBy(pd => pd.Product)
    //I'm not in a position to test if EF will successfully run the below, so .ToList()
    //May not be required. However, the bulk of the work is done in the database, anyway.
    //.ToList()
    .Select(g => new {
        OfficeId = g.Key.TariffCategory.Office.Id,
        Office = g.Key.TariffCategory.Office.Name,
        Category = g.Key.TariffCategory.Description,
        ArticleId = g.Key.Article.Id,
        Article = g.Key.Article.Title,
        Destinations = g.Select(gg => new { Id = gg.Destination.DestinationId, Name = gg.Destination.Description }),
        GlobalDestinations = g.Key.AllDestinationsInOffice,
        g.Key.Article.LastReviewedDate,
        g.Key.Article.CreatedDate,
        g.Key.Article.CreatedByEmployee
    });
```

I'm pretty sure the above *should* work without the `ToList()`, but I'm not confident to say it 100% will work. However, as noted, the bulk of the work is done in the database, the final projection shouldn't be too intensive, even if it's done in memory. However, should the `ToList()` be required, we would need to modify the `GroupBy` to return all fields we select via `Key`, otherwise we're going to have issues with lazy loading and N+1 queries.

Comment: That seems to work, thanks. I don't use `GroupBy` enough to do so without looking up some references. (And, yes, the `ToList()` was necessary.)